# How to display a blinking / flashing link in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, visualization

I am in need a link that will flash every 500 milleseconds, for a duration of 5 seconds...
I remember long ago having a link like this, but deleted it because one could only click it when it was visible. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You don't need a flashing link. These are not the codez you are looking for...

Comment: I knew it! One day, the blink-tag WILL be missed ;) Would you maybe like to let the blinking link slide slowly from the left to the right?

Comment: @moxn: and change colour! and Animated GIFs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var col = new String();
var x=1;var y;

function blink()
{
 if(x%2) 
 {
  col = "rgb(255,0,0)";
 }else{
  col = "rgb(255,255,255)";
 }

 aF.style.color=col;x++;if(x>2){x=1};setTimeout("blink()",500);
}
</script>


<body onload="blink()">

<a id="aF" href="http://www.google.com"><b>*Google!*</b><br>
```

Comment: Thank you! that at least solved the problem i had previously where i could not click the link when the text was hidden :)

Comment: added setTimeout("stopblink()",5000); to the bottom of your script... In stopblink() i simply changed the id aF and now it works as intended... Thanks again

Comment: @Sarfraz: I wonder how could someone alter your code in order to stop blinking upon clicking.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JavaScript function in [Script.aculo.us](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/combination-effects-demo) to do that : Have a look on **Effect.Pulsate**

Comment: Could I recommend some strobe lights and a nice drum-n-bass beat to go with that text effect?

Answer (score 1):

There is CSS

> text-decoration: blink

but that will blink your link all the time, you would need some javascript to change the style after 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the best way to do it, but unfortunately, blink isn't supported by IE, Safari, or Chrome: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_text-decoration.asp . It's part of CSS2, and browsers are supposed to support it, but add the option of disabling it to conform to WAI UAAG: http://www.w3.org/TR/UAAG/guidelines.html#tech-on-off-blinking-text

Answer (score 1):

Remember to always keep usability for all users in mind. Especially if you're making something flash at a certain frequency. [Just be careful.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy#Web_design)

Answer (score 0):

'A' quick JQuery UI version...
Links need CLASS 'flasher', and an ID

Will start on mouseover...and stop on mouseout.

Also add the secondarycolor as a hover to the 'A' link...it will help mask the initial interval delay at start.

```
var flashInterval;
var flasherId;
var firstColor = '#EF7F2C';
var secondaryColor = '#3296C8';
var flashTime = 300;

jQuery('a.flasher').mouseover(function() {
    if(flasherId){ jQuery('#'+flasherId).animate({ color:firstColor},0); }//stop any previous flashing link
    flasherId = jQuery(this).attr('id');//get id of current link
    //set interval
    flashInterval = setInterval(function(){ jQuery('#'+flasherId).animate({ color:secondaryColor},flashTime).animate({ color:firstColor},flashTime); },flashTime*2);
}).mouseout(function() {
    clearInterval(flashInterval);//clear interval
    jQuery('#'+flasherId).animate({ color:firstColor},0);//reset flasher
    flasherId = '';//clear flasher var
});
```